# Postgres raises error when I try filter information_schema.columns.column_name by non-existing column name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to filter out columns 'x' from my table and I don't know if this column exists at all. I wrote a query:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'T'
      AND column_name <> "X"
```

And it throws error:

```
[42703] ERROR: column "X" does not exist
```

Why? I tried to convert _column_name_ to string - it didn't work.

What the problem?

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.4 (Ubuntu 10.4-2.pgdg16.04+1)
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: `psql --version` shows you the version of the `psql` tool. That' **not** the version of the Postgres server. The `psql` client version is usually not important. To get the version of the server, run `select version()`

Comment: String literals need to be enclosed in [single quotes in SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS). Double quotes are for [identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671053

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Postgres say column does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671053/why-does-postgres-say-column-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the double quote ...

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'T'
    AND column_name <> 'X'
```

This should work ...

Answer (score 0):

Just applied a workaround like this:

```
select t.column_name
from (SELECT column_name :: text
      FROM information_schema.columns
      WHERE table_name = 'T') t
where t.column_name <> 'X'
```

Comment: It's not a "workaround" it's the correct way to write string literals in SQL